# How to record calls in android

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, android-fragments

I am new to android.I have seen many examples.but all doesn't help me.I want example or tutorial for **How to Record incoming and outgoing calls in android**.can anyone refer good tutorial for this?

Comment: If you can purchase code... this is good  http://www.chupamobile.com/android-full-applications/call-recorder-4151...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, for this first of all you need to use Device Policy Manager, and need to make your device Admin device. After that you have to create one BroadCaast receiver and one service. I am posting code here and its working fine.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
    private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
    private ComponentName mAdminName;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        try {
            // Initiate DevicePolicyManager.
            mDPM = (DevicePolicyManager) getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
            mAdminName = new ComponentName(this, DeviceAdminDemo.class);

            if (!mDPM.isAdminActive(mAdminName)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mAdminName);
                intent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION, "Click on Activate button to secure your application.");
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                // mDPM.lockNow();
                // Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                // TrackDeviceService.class);
                // startService(intent);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (REQUEST_CODE == requestCode) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TService.class);
                startService(intent);
        }
    }

}
```

//DeviceAdminDemo class

```
public class DeviceAdminDemo extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

    public void onEnabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    };

    public void onDisabled(Context context, Intent intent) {
    };
}
```

//TService Class

```
public class TService extends Service {
    MediaRecorder recorder;
    File audiofile;
    String name, phonenumber;
    String audio_format;
    public String Audio_Type;
    int audioSource;
    Context context;
    private Handler handler;
    Timer timer;
    Boolean offHook = false, ringing = false;
    Toast toast;
    Boolean isOffHook = false;
    private boolean recordstarted = false;

    private static final String ACTION_IN = "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE";
    private static final String ACTION_OUT = "android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL";
    private CallBr br_call;




    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("service", "destroy");

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // final String terminate =(String)
        // intent.getExtras().get("terminate");//
        // intent.getStringExtra("terminate");
        // Log.d("TAG", "service started");
        //
        // TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)
        // getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); // TelephonyManager
        // // object
        // CustomPhoneStateListener customPhoneListener = new
        // CustomPhoneStateListener();
        // telephony.listen(customPhoneListener,
        // PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        // context = getApplicationContext();

        final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(ACTION_OUT);
        filter.addAction(ACTION_IN);
        this.br_call = new CallBr();
        this.registerReceiver(this.br_call, filter);

        // if(terminate != null) {
        // stopSelf();
        // }
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public class CallBr extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Bundle bundle;
        String state;
        String inCall, outCall;
        public boolean wasRinging = false;

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_IN)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    state = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
                    if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                        inCall = bundle.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                        wasRinging = true;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "IN : " + inCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
                        if (wasRinging == true) {

                            Toast.makeText(context, "ANSWERED", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            String out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh-mm-ss").format(new Date());
                            File sampleDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "/TestRecordingDasa1");
                            if (!sampleDir.exists()) {
                                sampleDir.mkdirs();
                            }
                            String file_name = "Record";
                            try {
                                audiofile = File.createTempFile(file_name, ".amr", sampleDir);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();

                            recorder = new MediaRecorder();
//                          recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_CALL);

                            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.VOICE_COMMUNICATION);
                            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                            recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
                            try {
                                recorder.prepare();
                            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) { 
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            recorder.start();
                            recordstarted = true;
                        }
                    } else if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)) {
                        wasRinging = false;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "REJECT || DISCO", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        if (recordstarted) {
                            recorder.stop();
                            recordstarted = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_OUT)) {
                if ((bundle = intent.getExtras()) != null) {
                    outCall = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);
                    Toast.makeText(context, "OUT : " + outCall, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

//Permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

//Declare following thing in manifest:

Declare DeviceAdminDemo class to manifest:

```
 <receiver
            android:name="com.example.voicerecorder1.DeviceAdminDemo"
            android:description="@string/device_description"
            android:label="@string/device_admin_label"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_DISABLE_REQUESTED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

<service android:name=".TService" >
        </service>
```

//my_admin.xml

```
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <uses-policies>
        <force-lock />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

Comment: how ll be the output of this?

Comment: It will create one folder named "TestRecordingDasa1" and inside it "Record.amr" will generate which is your recorded call log.

Comment: can you send main_activity layout?

Comment: In that nothing inside it, no need to it all, just keep as it is!!!

Comment: oh ok ok.will this record,when i am getting call?

Comment: yes, ofcourse, for me its working fine, but for that first you need to make your device admin, using above code. And please accept and upvote the answer, so others can take benefit of this.

Comment: can you send full manifasted.xml file? please

Comment: You dont need full dear, just paste above lines in manifest and that's it.

Comment: i got error in <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/my_admin" />

Comment: becasuse i dont have my_admin xml file

Comment: Please create one xml file named "xml" under resource directory and then mut my_admin.xml inside it.

Comment: can u update that xml file?

Comment: I have did it @user3709680

Comment: ll this record only incoming call?or outgoing call?or both?

Comment: This is for Incoming Call , and you can modify code as per your need.

Comment: #pratik thank you soo much dear.i cant forget your help.thanks alot

Comment: @user3709680 is it working or not? and wats yr name?

Comment: Why the need for admin? Also, it seem like other solutions I've found, which don't always work

Answer (score 0):

well you could use an android app called Call Recorder from Google Play

[Call Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=polis.app.callrecorder)
i've never tried it before but it was the first link in go*gle 
good luck with that.

- Aaron PM

Comment: library doesn't seem to work well at all, even on Android 6.0.1 which it claims to support.